Passing in a generic templated subtype
Let's say I have a templated, abstract Fish class with two templated children:
template<typename T>
class Fish {
public:
    virtual ~Fish() = default;

    // Pure virtual method to make Fish an abstract class
    virtual void swim() const = 0;

    // A common method for all fish
    void breathe() const {
        std::cout << "Fish is breathing." << std::endl;
    }
};

// Templated Salmon class (child of Fish)
template<typename T>
class Salmon : public Fish<T> {
public:
    void swim() const override {
        std::cout << "Salmon is swimming with value = " << T << std::endl;
    }
};

// Templated Goldfish class (child of Fish)
template<typename T>
class Goldfish : public Fish<T> {
public:
    void swim() const override {
        std::cout << "Goldfish is swimming with value = " << T << std::endl;
    }
};

I want to make a non-templated Aquarium class, that stores a vector of Fish objects and has void addFish(Fish) and Fish removeFish() functions.
How would I do this?

How would I store the fish?
What would I put as the param/return for the AddFish/RemoveFish functions?

Something like this placeholder code
// Aquarium class (non-templated)
class Aquarium {
private:
    SomeType?? fishTank; // Store fish objects

public:
    // Add fish to the aquarium (now templated to handle any type of Fish<T>)
    template<typename T>
    void addFish(SomeType??? fish){...}

    template<typename T>
    SomeType??? removeFish(){...}

    // Method to make all fish swim
    void makeFishSwim() {
        for (auto& fish : fishTank) {
            fish->swim();
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Aquarium aquarium;

    // Create fish objects
    auto salmon = std::make_shared<Salmon<int>>();
    auto goldfish = std::make_shared<Goldfish<int>>();

    // Add fish to the aquarium doing something like this
    aquarium.addFish(salmon);
    aquarium.addFish(goldfish);

    // Make all fish swim
    aquarium.makeFishSwim();

    return 0;
}


OT: Something like std::cout << "Salmon is swimming with value = " << T << std::endl; will not work, as T is a type and not a value.

Give Fish a non-template base class?

As for the rest of the code and your problem, why do you need these classes to be templates? What are your requirements? What are your limitations? From those requirements and limitations, what is your analysis? What is your design? What is your actual assignment or exercise?

I am intentionally trying to obfuscate my actual use case with a toy example that I think demonstrates clearly enough what I'm trying to do. I want to be able to store all types of Fish in my Aquarium and treat all Fish the same - because they are all fundamentally just Fish. But Some of them might be Fish and some might be Fish etc... and the Aquarium doesn't care about what type of fish it it. It just wants to take in and store the Fish

The compiler doesn't see fish, it sees fish<int> and fish<Sea> , those are 2 classes that have nothing in common as far as the type system is concerned. Your question is how to store two unrelated classes in one container, the answer is using variant or a polymorphic non templated base class for both and store the pointers to that base.

Right, that's what I was thinking. The problem with variant is that I need to know in advance all the types I need to support. But yeah I was thinking like you're saying and I was hoping that somebody would tell me that there is a way

All standard containers are homogeneous, and you need one that is heterogeneous. It might be possible that frameworks such as Boost might have it, otherwise you need to make one yourself. With that said, your design seems flawed... Why would you want to have a Fish<int> and a Fish<Sea>? What is Sea supposed to be? What is the template type really supposed to be used for? What problem is it supposed to solve?

You deciding to skip details is a problem, because details about how Fish<int> and Fish<double> differ matters.  A template class is a near arbitrary type factory; the types produced can have almost nothing in common.  Is the only thing they have in common that they swim?  Or is it a complex contract?  The features that Fish<int> and Fish<double> differ on; does someone with access to an Aquarium ever (and I mean ever) need to have access to those differences?  If so, do they know the subtype of fish they are looking for?  Do you have a double-dispatch situation?

Because the correct answer to your toy problem is remove template<typename T> from class Fish as it does nothing, and std::cout << "Salmon is swimming with value = " << T << std::endl; doesn't compile.  At another extreme, modify Aquarium so that it supports anything at all that can Swim and store them by value.  Or something in the middle.  But it actually depends on why your fish types have templates involved at all and how much the identity as Fish matters?

I think this example covers what you are looking for:

Use abstract baseclass to model what a Fish can do, an interface : FishItf
You can make a vector out of those
A CRTP class for a reusable implementation (so you need no further generic Fish baseclass) called FishItfImpl. This pattern is great for avoiding diamond inheritance issues later
The use of typeid to get a somewhat usable string out of a templated type

See : https://onlinegdb.com/mzbURVQVV
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Begin with an abstract baseclass modeling
// what a fish can do
class FishItf
{
public:
    virtual void Swim() = 0;
    virtual ~FishItf() = default;
};


// Default reusable implmentation of the fish interface
template<typename FishType>
class FishItfImpl : public FishItf
{
public:
    void Swim() override
    {
        std::string name = typeid(FishType).name();
        auto pos = name.find_first_not_of("0123456789");
        name = name.substr(pos);

        // typeid allows you to get a unique name for the type (not quite the original class name)
        std::cout << name << " is swimming\n";
    }
};

// A salmon with default fish implementation
class Salmon :
    public FishItfImpl<Salmon>
{
};    

// And a bad ass brass can sing too
class BadAssBrass :
    public FishItfImpl<BadAssBrass>
{
public:
    void Sing()
    {
        std::cout << "Take me to the river...\n";
    }

};


int main()
{
    Salmon salmon;
    salmon.Swim();
    
    BadAssBrass brass;
    brass.Swim();
    brass.Sing();

    // But you can now also make a vector of FishItf
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<FishItf>> fishes;
    fishes.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Salmon>());
    fishes.emplace_back(std::make_unique<BadAssBrass>());

    std::cout << "\n\nLet all the fishes swim : \n";
    
    for(const auto& fish : fishes)
    {
        fish->Swim();
    }
};

